# Sinch Video calling sound is coming from front speaker

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I have implemented sinch video calling in ios swift project i have followed all process given in sinch implementation document https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/ios/#calling. And i am successfully able to implement but i am getting on issue my video sound in coming from front speaker. how can i solve this problem?? Below my code:

```
var client: SINClient?
var sinCall : SINCall?
```

Configuring sinch

```
//MARK: Configuring Sinch Delegate
func configuringSinch(){
    //Configuring Client Key
    client = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: Constants.SINCH_APP_KEY, applicationSecret: Constants.SINCH_PRIVATE_KEY, environmentHost: Constants.SANDBOX_ENVIRONMENT, userId: Utility().getUserId())

    client?.call().delegate = self
    client?.setSupportCalling(true)
    client?.enableManagedPushNotifications()
    client?.start()
    client?.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

    let vcCont = client?.videoController()
    self.vwLocalView.addSubview((vcCont?.localView())!)

    self.sinCall?.delegate = self

}

//MARK: Sinch Video Call Delegate
func clientDidStart(_ client: SINClient!) {
    print("Client Did Start")
}

func clientDidFail(_ client: SINClient!, error: Error!) {
    print("Client failed : \(error)")
    player?.stop()
}
func clientDidStop(_ client: SINClient!) {
    print("Client Did Stop")
    player?.stop()
}

    //MARK: Video Call Did Recieve
func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
    print("Did Recieve Incoming Call")

    playRingtoneSound() // Playing Audio
    call.delegate = self;
    self.sinCall = call
}

 //MARK: Call Did Add Video Track
func callDidAddVideoTrack(_ call: SINCall!) {
    let videoCont = client?.videoController()
    vwRemoteView.addSubview((videoCont?.remoteView())!)
}

func callDidEnd(_ call: SINCall!) {
    sinCall?.hangup()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can manage **SINAudioController** to manage audio output.

```
func audioController() -> SINAudioController {
        return (client?.audioController())!
    }

//MARK: Video Call Did Recieve
func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
    audioController().enableSpeaker()

    playRingtoneSound() // Playing Audio
    call.delegate = self;
    self.sinCall = call
}

// In SINCallDelegate
func callDidEstablish(_ call: SINCall!) {

    //to disableSpeaker
    audioController().disableSpeaker()
}
```

**try this to manage AudioOutput Session manually**

```
// MARK: AudioOutput Session

// to enable front speaker manually
func setSessionPlayerOn()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)
    } catch _ {
    }
}

// to enable speaker manually
func setSessionPlayerSpeaker()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } catch _ {
    }
}

// to turnoff AudioOutput Session manually
func setSessionPlayerOff()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch _ {
    }
}
```

Comment: its not about incoming sound i am taking when we do video calling.

Comment: ok but as you wrote video sound in coming from front speaker it will make the output from speaker. you can use it anywhere in controller audioController().enableSpeaker(). let me know if it would help

Comment: i have edited the answer as audioController().enableSpeake not working for you. you can manage AudioOutput Session manually to achieve this.

Comment: does your problem still exists?

Comment: Fixed The Problem @Govind

Comment: Does my answer help? if it does mark as answered and close the problem. @S.Bharti

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
 func callDidEstablish(_ call: SINCall!) {

    let audio = APPDELEGATE.client?.audioController()
    audio?.disableSpeaker()

   // self.startCallDurationTimerWithSelector()
    appDelegate.client?.audioController().stopPlayingSoundFile()

}
```

this is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainVC: UIViewController,SINCallDelegate {
   // var client: SINClient?

    private let videoController = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.videoController()
    private let audioController = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.audioController()


    private let callClient: SINCallClient
    private var call: SINCall!

    let username: String

    @IBOutlet weak var otherView: UIView!

   // private var mainView: SinchView { return view as! SinchView }

    @IBAction func call_btn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        answer()
    }
    @IBAction func end_btn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        decline()
    }


    override func loadView() {
       // view = SinchView()
        view = otherView
    }

    init(username: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.callClient = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.call()

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        print("init(coder:) has not been implemented " + String(describing: aDecoder))

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented " + String(describing: aDecoder))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        call.delegate = self

        //self.mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.localView())
        otherView.addSubview((self.videoController?.localView())!)

        self.videoController?.localView().contentMode = .scaleToFill

        if self.call.direction == SINCallDirection.incoming {
            self.audioController?.startPlayingSoundFile(self.pathForSound(string: "incoming.wav") as String, loop: true)
        }

        if self.call.details.isVideoOffered {
            print("video offered")
            //self.mainView.videoView.addSubview(self.videoController.localView())
            otherView.addSubview((self.videoController?.localView())!)

            self.videoController?.localView().contentMode = .scaleToFill
        }

        otherView.addSubview((self.videoController?.localView())!)
       // mainView.answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answer), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
       // mainView.declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(decline), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.audioController?.enableSpeaker()
    }

    func pathForSound(string: String) -> NSString {
        let nsSt = Bundle.main.resourcePath! as NSString

        return nsSt.appendingPathComponent(string) as NSString
    }

    func answer() {
        call.answer()
    }

    func decline() {
        call.hangup()
    }

    func callDidEstablish(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidEstablish")
        let audio = SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.audioController()
        audio?.disableSpeaker()

        // self.startCallDurationTimerWithSelector()
       SinchManager.sharedInstance.client!.audioController().stopPlayingSoundFile()
    }

    func callDidEnd(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidEnd")
    }

    func callDidProgress(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidProgress")
        self.audioController?.startPlayingSoundFile(self.pathForSound(string: "ringback.wav") as String, loop: true)
    }

    func callDidAddVideoTrack(call: SINCall!) {
        print("callDidAddVideoTrack")
        otherView.addSubview((self.videoController?.localView())!)
    }
```